# Cannot get the threads to work in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that makes five simple threads with the PrintHello methods. I want to be able to run this program and see how the threads will work and when they will print out. I know that a thread splits the time between tasks. So a task might run for 1 second while the other task might only get .01 seconds but it gives the illusion that all programs were running at once.

I want my program to be able to demonstrate how a thread will work and also would like it so that I can changed the number of threads to more or less than 5.

**The first line creates an array of threads.**
      pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

**the for loop iterates through the length of the array.**
      for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
         ...
      }

**This line of code will create the thread:**
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL,PrintHello, (void *)i);

**This will exit the thread.**
      pthread_exit(NULL);

**Errors that I am getting are listed at the bottom of this window.**

Code:

```
#include "pthread.h"
#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << tid << endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    int i;
    for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, 
                          PrintHello, (void *)i);
      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory   c:\users\itpr13266\desktop\c++\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp  6   1   TestProject
    2   IntelliSense: cannot open source file "pthread.h"   c:\users\itpr13266\desktop\c++\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp  6   1   TestProject
    3   IntelliSense: identifier "pthread_exit" is undefined    c:\users\itpr13266\desktop\c++\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp  79  4   TestProject
    4   IntelliSense: identifier "pthread_t" is undefined   c:\users\itpr13266\desktop\c++\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp  84  2   TestProject
    5   IntelliSense: identifier "pthread_create" is undefined  c:\users\itpr13266\desktop\c++\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp  89  12  TestProject
    6   IntelliSense: identifier "pthread_exit" is undefined    c:\users\itpr13266\desktop\c++\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp  96  4   TestProject
```

Comment: Pretty obvious - it can't find `pthread.h`. Try `#include <pthread.h>`.

Comment: You're doing this in devstudio, which means you're not properly including the pthread windows shim into your project (windows does not natively expose pthreads). You can fix the `#include`, and maybe even get this to work, but I'll tell you straight up, if you can use VS2012 or later, ditch *all* of this and use the [C++11 `<thread>` support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). (and btw, you're not joining any of your launched threads, which is likely a bug).

Comment: I am using Visual C++ visual studio 2010.

Comment: #include <pthread.h>    <-- that gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, Visual Studio does not know about pthreads.
So, you should include pthreads library in your project.

Here is the first link I found in google:

http://linqtolinq.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/setting-up-pthreads-in-windows-under-visual-studio/